# Php: How to cut specific part of a string?

Tags: php, html, css, string, replace

**THE SITUATION:**

I need to cut a specific part of a string. That part will not always be the same in length and content.

The only thing i know is that it will always start with:  and finish with:

All the content in the middle must cut out (head tag included).

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i cut a specific part of a string knowing only the begin and the end of that part?

**EDIT:**

For example from this string i have to remove the part that is contained into the head tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<style><!--
.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 12pt;
font-family:Calibri
}
--></style></head>
<body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>Hello!                         
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: regular expressions.

Comment: Honestly i don't know how to approach it. I know str_replace can remove 'hello' from 'hello world'. But in my case the only thing i know is that that part of the string will be contained into two head tags. I don't know how to remove that and all in between.

Comment: have you tried using strpos to get position of ur first : then using substring on that position+1 to get next : ?

Comment: but i don't know the length of the string

Comment: you don't need to know it, when using substring, first arg is ur string, second one is where to start (there you could put the position frorm strpos +1) and then u would get new string from the first : forward. Then use strpos again to get position index of ur last? sum up the second positionn and there you go, u have both starting : and ending :

Comment: Why don't you try to use a DOM Parser? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hello guys. Thank you for the feedback. But can you delucidate please the mistake i made? I needed to cut a speficic part of a string in php and since didn't know how to approach it and since didn't found a proper solution searching in google and SO i have made a question about it. That may be useful for other people that have the same need. In which exact meaning is intended 'too broad' in this case? How can i make it more narrow in my case? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the stupid-proof way?

```
<?php

$myString = "<html>
<head>
<style><!--
.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 12pt;
font-family:Calibri
}
--></style></head>
<body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>Hello!                         
</div>
</body>
</html>";

$begin = strpos($myString, '<head>');
$end   = strpos($myString, '</head>');

$final = substr($myString, 0, $begin) . substr($myString, $end+7);

var_dump($final);
?>
```

Comment: It does remove also what is contained between the head tag?

Comment: yes. try it on phpfiddle.org

Comment: Thank you! is working exactly as i needed!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$str = "hello:evening:";
echo preg_replace("/\:[^)]+\:/","",$str);
```

This will give only "hello"

Comment: Ah ok. So basically in my case i have to replace the first : with <head> and the second : with </head>  right?

Comment: yes.. whatever the string within ' : : ' will be removed..